# How to run code (macro?) for all datasets in a lib?

Tags: loops, sas, dataset, export-to-excel, sas-macro

I have tried finding answer with searching forum without finding a solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=listing%20over%20datasets%20sas

```
/* make all letters lower case */
data steg1;
set steg0b;
email = lowcase(email);
run;

/* stripping down email column */
data steg2;
set steg1;
email = strip(email);
run;
```

I want to run a certain code (long one, I posted a part of it) over all datasets in a certain library (probably loop is the correct way). The library is an excel file with all its sheets (which needs to be transformed in different ways, in the datastep). The output wanted is another file in the same directory as the origin, with a suitable name as "cleaned.xlsx" or similar.

I share some code:

```
%let filepath=
\\mynetworkpath\;

%let filname=
tobecleaned.xlsx;

%let file=
&filepath.\&filename;


libname epostimp xlsx "&file.";
```

That makes me getting a library called epostimp where I find the different sheets, lets call it Norway, Denmark, Sweden.

I now want to execute my datastep for the three datasets.

Thereafter I want to export them to the same excel file which I want to call cleaned.xlsx (in cleaned.xlsx I want to see the sheets Norway, Denmark, Sweden - just as in the original).

The problems will be:

- How to make a loop with my datastep
- How to rename the finish datasets to the correct ones; Norway, Denmark, Sweden
- How to export them into one excel file called cleaned.xlsx

Would be glad to hear some suggestions of how to make it.

Comment: Thanks. Hope someone knows a solution for running program over all datasets at one time.

Comment: Did you try making a macro that copies/modifies one sheet?  You could then use proc contents or other tools to get a list of sheets into a dataset and use  `call execute()` to generate one macro call for each sheet.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your tip!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is essentially what you are looking for. Keep in mind that the EXCEL engine will create sheets and ranges of the specified names, but that usually doesn't matter.

Essentially, treating both files as libraries, one can iterate over the library members in the input file (input library), recreating them under the same name in the output file (output library).

Keep in mind, this code is not very robust, and will generate an error if the output file already exists. One could include deleting and creating a new file automatically, but it seems preferable to err on the side of caution. Also, if the sheet names contain spaces or special characters, this may cause some issues with the iteration. For example, having a sheet named "Sheet 1" would cause "ii" to iterate over "Sheet" and "1" separately.

```
%macro loop_over_sheets(in_file, out_file);
    libname in_lib excel "&in_file.";
    libname out_lib excel "&out_file.";

    %local ii ds_name ds_names;

    /*  Get the dataset names. */
    proc sql noprint;
        select  memname into :ds_names separated by ' '
            from dictionary.members
                where upcase(LIBNAME) = 'IN_LIB';
    quit;

    %do ii = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&ds_names.));
        %let ds_name = %scan(&ds_names., &ii.);

        data out_lib.&ds_name.;
            set in_lib."&ds_name.$"n;

            /* ... your code here ... */
        run;
    %end;

    libname in_lib clear;
    libname out_lib clear;
%mend loop_over_sheets;

%loop_over_sheets(&file., &filepath.cleaned.xlsx);
```

The last line uses the given file and filepath macro variables from your example. Modify as needed.